# can I store my boiled hopped wort

Tags: bittering

Can I boil my hops in a gallon of wort for bittering, then store it in a Masson jar in my fridge for a week?  Will this hold its properties?

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses.  Both very helpful.  In addition, if I made a hop tea for aroma and flavor, could this be held in an air tight container then added later to my chilled wort?

Comment: hop tea, only using water would work. but boil it, put it in a canning jar, lightly close and put in fridge, it should seal it. (must be a canning jar with 2 part lid.)
other wise make it on your brew day.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could, in theory, do this.

boiling in that small of a scale, you will lose hop utilization, and maybe difficult to calculate final IBUs.

also sanitation, if you add this to post boil wort to bitter, there is a chance of introducing other things that may spoil your beer....

Comment: I agree.  It's likely to harbor some form of wild contamination, and should be boiled again for a few minutes when ready to use just to kill off anything that might have found its way in there.